# Generics with inheritance issue

Tags: java, generics

Please, consider my code:

```
class Fruit {}

class Apple extends Fruit {}

class Pear extends Fruit {}

abstract class AbstractProducer<T extends AbstractProducer, S extends Fruit> {

    /**
     * Finds same type producers,for example apple producers from USA.
     * @return
     */
    public List<T> findSameCountryProducers() {...}

    public S produce(){...}

    public void getAppleFromSameCountryProducer(Function<T, Apple> func) {... }

}

class USAProducer<T extends Fruit> extends AbstractProducer<USAProducer<T>, T> {}
```

I have a problem with this method `public void getAppleFromSameCountryProducer(Function<T, Apple> func)` because it allows to use `Producer<Pear>` to produce apple what is wrong. I need to allow to use here only same type producers that produce apples. Could anyone say how to fix it (at the same time `public List<T> findSameCountryProducers` must work)?

Comment: Try `T extends AbstractProducer<T, S>` in `AbstractProducer` definition. And I'd suggest using `P` and `F` instead of `T` and `S` for `Producer` and `Fruit` generics, might help reading the code.

Comment: @sp00m No, it didn't help. I need to do something like `Function<T<Apple>, Apple> func`.

Comment: I think you need to clarify further. You have a method in the abstract class that explicitly, by its name and signature, deals with Apples. And that's not what you want? What do you want, then?

Comment: Dont you think that the method getAppleFromSameCountryProducer should not be at the AbstractProducer class? If a country does not produce Apple?

Comment: You shouldn't be using a method with concrete fruits, i.e. `Apple` in the abstract class. The abstract class deals with generic fruits and generic producers. So try changing the method to something like `getFruitsFromSameCountryProducer(Function<T, S> func)`